# JMeter if condition throws java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Tags: jmeter

JMeter throws below exception when if condition is false

For example
In IF controller if we use 1==1, it works with out any issues.
But, if we use 1==2 then it works fine skipping the statements under thread group. but throws below exception in log statement. Appreciate, if any one can help on this issue

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

I was using this condition initially ${__groovy( "${__machineIP()}"=="10.0.0.4")} and below is error if condition fails(i.e IP is not 10.0.0.4) `at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.compareToWithEqualityCheck(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:597) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7] at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.compareEqual(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:621) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7] at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:708) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]`

Comment: Can you show full exception?

Comment: I was using this condition initially ${__groovy( "${__machineIP()}"=="10.0.0.4")} and below is error if condition fails(i.e IP is not 10.0.0.4) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.compareToWithEqualityCheck(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:597) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.compareEqual(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:621) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:708) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use groovy/java syntax:

```
${__groovy( "10.0.0.4".equals(JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIP()))
```

Don't use `${` syntax inside `__groovy` function

Comment: Thanks for your help, when I run it with above condition in distributed environment. It is returning below exception        java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(BufferedWriter.java:109) ~[?:1.8.0_111]

Comment: @AnilKumar you should share your test plan (or relevant parts) , what's the if controller under?

Comment: Hi, If Controller is under ThreadGroup

Answer (score 0):

Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into Grooovy scripts.

Either go for [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) like:

```
${__jexl3("${__machineIP()}"=="10.0.0.4",)}
```

or amend your __groovy() function to use the [underlying __machineIP() logic](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/aapache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#getLocalHostIP--):

```
${__groovy(org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIP() == '10.0.0.4',)}
```

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)